# Proving n^2 = O(log n)

Tags: asymptotics

This is how I would think it
n^2 = O(log n)

f(n) <= c*g(n)

should c=1 ?

n0 = 1

n^2 <= log n

0 <=  log n - n^2, for all n>=1

we take n=1 then 0 <= log(1) - 1^2

0 <= 0 - 1

0 <= -1

Therefore n^2 = O(logn) false?

Is this correct?

Comment: No, this is false. As for your attempt, you don't get to set $n=1$; you need to show the inequality for *all* $n \geq n_0$.

Comment: How exactly? can you  give a helping hand ? :) I'm having trouble figuring out proofs

Comment: You have to show that no matter how large you choose c, and no matter how large you choose n_0, you will find n ≥ n_0 where n^2 > c log n. You might try to find an n such that n ≥ n_0, n > c, and n > log n.

Comment: @crystyxn You need to look at the definition of O again -- it's all there. As for helping with the task at hand, you'll notice that a lengthy answer at the question I linked you was written by me.